# App crashes on FroYo on start of new activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar

I am writing an android app for devices 2.1 Froyo > 3.1 Honeycomb.

The way I have been doing this is through classes for Java that are supposed to be for all platforms and having different layouts based on screen size, is this the correct way to be going about it?

I have written the layouts for Honeycomb, and I have just started implementing and testing on Froyo (my other device), and I cannot launch any of the other activities on Froyo or Gingerbread (emulator) without them crashing, but they work perfectly on Honeycomb.

Here is the LogCat for the crash:

> 07-11 11:17:51.832:
>   INFO/ActivityManager(75): Displayed
>   com.squirculardesign.android.pixel/.Main:
>   +6s867ms (total +24s424ms)
>
> 07-11 11:17:57.063:
>   DEBUG/dalvikvm(223): GC_EXPLICIT freed
>   23K, 50% free 2827K/5639K, external
>   4681K/5342K, paused 72ms
>
> 07-11 11:18:21.743:
>   DEBUG/dalvikvm(75): GC_CONCURRENT
>   freed 1299K, 59% free 4249K/10247K,
>   external 3520K/3903K, paused 8ms+55ms
>
> 07-11 11:18:39.642:
>   WARN/KeyCharacterMap(458): No keyboard
>   for id 0
>
> 07-11 11:18:39.642:
>   WARN/KeyCharacterMap(458): Using
>   default keymap:
>   /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
>
> 07-11 11:18:40.064:
>   WARN/InputManagerService(75): Window
>   already focused, ignoring focus gain
>   of:
>   com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4067db20
>
> 07-11 11:18:51.223:
>   INFO/ActivityManager(75): Starting:
>   Intent {
>   cmp=com.squirculardesign.android.pixel/.Calculator_CaptureOriented
>   } from pid 458
>
> 07-11 11:18:51.543: INFO/dalvikvm(75):
>   Jit: resizing JitTable from 1024 to
>   2048
>
> 07-11 11:18:51.623:
>   INFO/dalvikvm(458): Could not find
>   method
>   com.squirculardesign.android.pixel.Calculator_CaptureOriented.getActionBar,
>   referenced from method
>   com.squirculardesign.android.pixel.Calculator_CaptureOriented.onStart
>
> 07-11 11:18:51.643:
>   WARN/dalvikvm(458): VFY: unable to
>   resolve virtual method 77:
>   Lcom/squirculardesign/android/pixel/Calculator_CaptureOriented;.getActionBar
>   ()Landroid/app/ActionBar;
>
> 07-11 11:18:51.643:
>   DEBUG/dalvikvm(458): VFY: replacing
>   opcode 0x6e at 0x0003
>
> 07-11 11:18:51.643:
>   DEBUG/dalvikvm(458): VFY: dead code
>   0x0006-000b in
>   Lcom/squirculardesign/android/pixel/Calculator_CaptureOriented;.onStart
>   ()V
>
> 07-11 11:18:51.773:
>   WARN/ResourceType(458): Failure
>   getting entry for 0x7f030002 (t=2 e=2)
>   in package 0 (error -75)
>
> 07-11 11:19:01.282:
>   WARN/ActivityManager(75): Activity
>   idle timeout for
>   HistoryRecord{40554050
>   com.squirculardesign.android.pixel/.Calculator_CaptureOriented}
>
> 07-11 11:19:22.253:
>   DEBUG/dalvikvm(153): GC_CONCURRENT
>   freed 503K, 52% free 2973K/6151K,
>   external 1625K/2137K, paused 7ms+5ms
>
> 07-11 11:20:23.573:
>   DEBUG/SntpClient(75): request time
>   failed: java.net.SocketException:
>   Address family not supported by
>   protocol
>
> 07-11 11:25:23.583:
>   DEBUG/SntpClient(75): request time
>   failed: java.net.SocketException:
>   Address family not supported by
>   protocol

I think (I'm unsure) that it is something to do with the ActionBar. 
Can anyone point out what the issue is and how to fix it?

Thanks for any help and have a great day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Activity.getActionBar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getActionBar%28%29) method doesn't exist before Honeycomb. But more generally, you'll need to replicate the functionality you have in the Action Bar for pre-Honeycomb devices since it doesn't exist for them.

Comment: I have been going about that by having menu items which display in the pop up menu on devices < Honeycomb and having them  in the actionbar in Honeycomb.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you used APIs specific to Honeycomb and they don't work on Froyo. If you target both Froyo and Honeycomb, I suggest you start with lowest API (that is Froyo).

> The way I have been doing this is
>   through classes for Java that are
>   supposed to be for all platforms and
>   having different layouts based on
>   screen size, is this the correct way
>   to be going about it?

Yes it's correct way to do it (Different resolutions to be precise). Just make sure you use APIs compatible with all levels of Android that you support.

Finally, your log does not show errors. Look for something that has `ERROR` in it and/or stack trace.